# Add or Subtract a certain number of pixels from existing position using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, position

I am animating a div that is absolutely positioned. The "top" value is deturmined dynamically, so I need to use jquery to animate -20px of whatever the dyanmic "top" value is.

```
$("#element").animate({"top" : +-20});
```

Obviously the above is incorrect, but I need to simply subtract 20 from whatever "top" value the #element already has. Can I do this using the above syntax?

For instance, if #element has a top: -300px, I would need the end result to be -320px.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to pass it a string, prepending `-=` to your number:

```
$("#element").animate({ top: "-=20" });
```

Comment: upvoted, but consider using the javascript name .animate({top:'-=20'}), rather than "top". using the javascript names means it doesn't need to parse the string first, processes faster.

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey - I never knew that it's faster. Can you point me to some source/test?

Comment: I set up a quick jsPerf, the difference is small with one item but adds up with the more things you do = http://jsperf.com/javascript-names-vs-strings-in-jquery

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey - The reason for that difference is because jQuery has to map the CSS property names to their native DOM property names. Testing only non-snake-cased property names results in a negligible difference in performance: http://jsperf.com/javascript-names-vs-strings-in-jquery/2

Comment: hmm, fair enough. So what you're saying is that it makes no difference with non-snake-cased properties, but is better for snake-cased properties? how is it then not best practice to use the native DOM property names?

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey - For many people, using snake-cased property names are easier to read, since they look like regular CSS.